# Dereferencing shared pointer and call by reference

Tags: c++, qt, shared-ptr

I use some fork of QMapControl and found a bug. [GeometryPointImage](https://github.com/TheDZhon/QMapControl/blob/develop/QMapControl/src/QMapControl/GeometryPointImage.cpp) has getter for image `const QPixmap& image() const`:

```
const QPixmap& GeometryPointImage::image() const
{
    // Is the image pixmap currently null?
    if (m_image == nullptr) { //std::shared_ptr<QPixmap> m_image;
        // Have we already constructed the null image pixmap?
        if (m_image_null == nullptr) { //std::unique_ptr<QPixmap> m_image_null;
            // Construct the null image pixmap.
            m_image_null.reset(new QPixmap);
        }
        // Return the null image pixmap.
        return *(m_image_null.get());
    } else {
        // Return the image pixmap.
        return *(m_image.get());
    }
}
```

There are various setters for `m_image`, and `image()` getter is used in `draw()` function:

```
painter.drawPixmap(-pixmap_rect_px.rawRect().width() / 2.0, -pixmap_rect_px.rawRect().height() / 2.0, image()); // void drawPixmap(int x, int y, const QPixmap &pm)
```

I can catch behaviour like this: `draw()` function calls `image()` that dereferences shared pointer, it goes into `drawPixmap` and some other event calls `setImage()` where `m_image` assigns to new value, and destructor of shared pointer destructs `QPixmap` object referenced by `drawPixmap()` and then app goes SIGSEGV.

I think getter that returns reference to something owned by shared pointer is no such good practice, but what is most suitable solution? I don't want to copy `QPixMap` object or add a mutex into getters, setters and `draw()`. Is there a way to prolong life of referenced object (with something similar to `qAsConst` maybe)? Should getter return `std::shared_ptr<QPixmap>`?

UPD:
In details: `setImage()` is called from main thread and this setter is expected to emit signal to redraw object. But [QMapControl main class](https://github.com/TheDZhon/QMapControl/blob/develop/QMapControl/src/QMapControl/QMapControl.cpp#L1424) also uses `QtConcurrent::run()` to redraw whole scene, and it touches pixmap from some other thread. And thread #1 deleting object when thread e.g. #6 (or #7) does `drawPixmap()`.

Comment: _ it goes into `drawPixmap` and some other event calls `setImage()`_ While `drawPixmap()` draws the image there shouldn't be any other event. Events are queued (per-thread) and the event loop is the top-most caller. So, while an event is processed no other event can be processed. Most GUI stuff isn't intended for multi-threading and hence not thread-safe. If you want to add multi-threading you have to manage it outside and by yourself.

Comment: _I think getter that returns reference to something owned by shared pointer is no such good practice_ If the class of the getter is one of the owners I don't see the danger. A const reference is in general prone to life time issues. If the referenced object is destroyed due to any reason then the const reference becomes dangling. `std::shared_ptr` doesn't contribute additionally to this fact, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't expect someone to give another answer to this question by now, so let there be my solution, it may help someone who will face such a problem later:

```
std::shared_ptr<QPixmap> GeometryPointImage::image() const
{
    // Is the image pixmap currently null?
    if (m_image == nullptr)
    {
        // Have we already constructed the null image pixmap?
        if (m_image_null == nullptr)
        {
            // Construct the null image pixmap.
            m_image_null.reset(new QPixmap);
        }

        // Return the null image pixmap.
        return std::make_shared<QPixmap>(*m_image_null.get());
    }
    else
    {
        // Return the image pixmap.
        return m_image;
    }
}

....

painter.drawPixmap(-pixmap_rect_px.rawRect().width() / 2.0, -pixmap_rect_px.rawRect().height() / 2.0, *image());
```

Now, returning a `shared_ptr` prolongates QPixMap's lifetime even if it has been reset by something else. Moreover, `image()` method was only used in class and nowhere from outside, so it was easy to fix this issue.